# Attaching a File to an logging report sent via email by Nlog

Tags: c#, vb.net, logging, nlog

I am using NLog to send a log report of my program to my email in vb.net (and I
managed to complete it for one type of log(only debug)).By default, the destination address and other requirements are taken from a XML file called Nlog.config.
Now I would like to attach a file to the log and I have no Idea how to do it , Does anybody have any hint?
Thanks

P.s. I am a Junior programmer, please forgive me if I was not enough clear :(

Comment: How about making it a 64 bit string and then adding to the log file.

Comment: @jdweng would you please explain a little more?

Comment: Using Convert.ToBase64String("string") and Convert.FromBase64String("string") will allow the packed string to be added to an xml element so you can attached the file contents.

Comment: Seems like it might be better to upload the file so somewhere such as AWS, Azure, or a fileshare, then provide a hyperlink to the file within the email.

Comment: @hitesh
Thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

Currently the NLog mail target won't support attachments

You need to create a custom target in NLog for this, see https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-target

You could copy the source code of the current `MailTarget`, see https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/master/src/NLog/Targets/MailTarget.cs

Comment: I have already checked the Nlog.target, but could not find any detail about attachment, Is there any way to attach a file using nlog.target?

Comment: As I said, it's **not** supported now. You need a custom target.